# Overloading Stored Procedures using C# and LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I have a .NET project in which I call several stored procedures using the LINQ to SQL method.

Several of these stored procedures are overloaded.  As in, they contain optional parameters and I may call the stored procedure in my code using any number of combinations of those parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateRecord]
    @ID    INT,
    @Name  VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @Date  DATETIME     = NULL

AS
BEGIN

    STORED PROCEDURE HERE

END
```

And then I'll call them in code like this:

```
DataContext.sp_UpdateRecord(ID, Name);
```

or

```
DataContext.sp_UpdateRecord(ID, DateTime.Now);
```

depending on the situation.

Of course, when you compile your DBML, it'll throw an exception saying "sp_UpdateRecord does not take 2 arguments"

So far, my solution has been to keep a .txt file in my project handy and keep the DBML definitions of those overridden stored procedures in that file and then every time I have to rebuild the DBML, I just manually copy/paste and replace it with the overridden definitions.

Obviously this is not ideal and can get tedious having to do this every time you rebuild the DBML.  It is also difficult and tedious to explain to the other developers how to do this and why I do this when they work on the same project.

Does anyone have any easy ways to overcome this?  I would prefer to continue calling my stored procedures using LINQ to SQL instead of the standard CommandExecute way.

Comment: `DataContext.sp_UpdateRecord(ID, Name);` or `DataContext.sp_UpdateRecord(ID, Email);`  you can't do this because name and email same datatype, the system has no way of differentiating between Name and Email.  You will need to pass three parameters, one can be null, either the second or the third parameter and then handle the process inside the stored procedure.

Comment: Yes you can, like I said, I'm manually modifying the DBML definitions of each stored procedure to adhere to the parameters.  And those manually overridden definitions are what I am keeping in the .txt file and manually replacing every time I rebuild the DBML.

Comment: However, what I wrote is just a generic example.  It's not the exact sample I'm using and I don't think I have any stored procedures that are using conflicting parameter types like that.  Don't focus so much on the actual example, instead focus on the problem I'm having.

Comment: I'm with Allen on this one, fix your design: sp_updaterecord(Id, null, Date) and then sp_updaterecord(Id, Name, null) are not only a lot easier to understand, they will also fix your DBML issue.

Comment: I think it's better if you handle the overload in sql server. for example: DataContext.sp_updaterecord(action, id, valor). In your store procedure you can check if action = 'email' then do something else if action = 'name' then do something...

Comment: RandomUs - the reason I'm doing it the way I am because I'm not sure how to pass null DateTime values into a SQL Stored Procedure.  I always get exception errors when I pass a null or any variation of specifically for DateTime values.  If I remember correctly, it'll tell me that DateTime is not a nullable value.  Can someone tell me the best way to pass a null DateTime value?